# IE | Edge Issue with border on table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having an issue with applying border on the table row ( tr element). Border gets applied on all browsers except IE.

I have added below to table:

```
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

   table tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
```

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/1t9kazfe/

Kindly let me know why it's not appearing on IE 11 / Edge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a issue with position: relative; , which i have removed from td and its working now. check snippet.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F7F8FA;
}

.comparison-logo {
  width: 55px;
  height: 41px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.v2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #313131;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

.v2 td {
  padding: 15px;
}

.v2 th {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: .9375rem;
}

.v2 tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.v2 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.v2-table td {
  height: 81px;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.v2 td {
  padding: 0.9375rem 0;
}

.pricing-table--description,
.pricing-table--number {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.v2-table td:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color: #F0F2F4!important;
}

.v2 .v2-responsive-table .v2-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.v2-bg--white,
.v2 .v2-bg--white {
  background-color: #fff!important;
}

.v2 *,
.v2 ::after,
.v2 ::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.v2 .v2-table.v2-table--padded td:first-child,
.v2 .v2-table.v2-table--padded th:first-child {
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
}

.v2 .v2-table:not(.v2-table--disabled-col-h-padding) td,
.v2 .v2-table:not(.v2-table--disabled-col-h-padding) th {
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="v2">
  <div class="">
    <div id="pricing" class="pricing">
      <div class="v2-responsive-table">
        <div class="v2-content-scroll-shadow__content">
          <div class="v2-content-scroll-shadow-arrow__ph v2-hidden"><span class="v2-content-scroll-shadow-arrow"><span class="v2-content-scroll-shadow-arrow__line"></span><span class="v2-content-scroll-shadow-arrow__arrow"></span></span>
          </div>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="v2-table v2-bg--white v2-table--th-hc v2-table--td-hc v2-table--flip v2-table--padded">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class=" v2-table__fixed-col">
                  <img style="width:55px;height:41px;display:block;margin:auto;" class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                </th>
                <th>
                  <img class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                  <p style="font-size:0.6rem; line-height:0.8rem; color:#9B9B9B; margin:0;">account1</p>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <img class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                </th>
                <th>
                  <img class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                  <p style="font-size:0.6rem; line-height:0.8rem; color:#9B9B9B; margin:0;">account2</p>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <img class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                </th>
                <th>
                  <img class="comparison-logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class=" v2-table__fixed-col"> <span class="pricing-table--number" style="color: #0076ff">0.15%</span><span class="pricing-table--description">value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number">0.18%</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number">0.18%</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number">0.18%</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number">0.2375%</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number">0.25%</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">value</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class=" v2-table__fixed-col"> <span class="pricing-table--number" style="color: #0076ff"> 90</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number"> 80</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number"> 100</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number"> 100</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number"> 95</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
                <td> <span class="pricing-table--number"> 150</span><span class="pricing-table--description" style="">Min value</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sumit , thanks for response but I need to have background color in td . color for td background color and border for tr are different. If I set tr{border-bottom:1px solid black} then also border does not appear on IE/edge whereas for rest of browsers it appears

Comment: There was a issue with position: relative; , which i have removed from td and its working now, please check updated answer.

Comment: did this helped?